# Intellij doesn't find certain keywords of ScalaTest library

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalatest

I add ScalaTest to my IntelliJ project dependencies in Test scope(tried compile also) but even though IntelliJ finds classes like Flatspec and Matchers it doesn't find keywords like should and in. I am not using SBT [image: Dependencies] [image: Compile Error]

Comment: I don't think it doesn't recognize `should`. I think you might be using it wrong. See [here](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/using_matchers). What is the error message you're getting?

Comment: I have similar problems with an SBT project and ScalaTest. Newest versions of everything. Cleared the caches, re-imported the project, nothing helped. I have to live with lots of squiggly red lines in the test code.